# Hi, I am using mongo-oplog and I am just trying to get my replication set. However, nothing prints out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I mongod, nodejs, and download mongo-oplog. My replication is set is working on my computer .I have tried to run a replication set on my computer ,while I try to access it from node.js but I still nothing. Am I missing a piece of code ?

```
var MongoOplog = require('mongo-oplog');
var oplog = MongoOplog('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local', { ns: 'test.posts' }).tail();
console.log("Please Work");
oplog.on('op', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert some data in posts collection in the test database? All your program does is tail the oplog. You need something else to insert some data, e.g. open a mongo shell and run:

```
use test
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {db.posts.insert({x:i})}
```